# Visualize scatter plot with labels on each point

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

i have a dataset longitude, latitude, its city, and the status of its city of coronavirus.
I want to give a label on each point for city name. i dont have any idea if i use plt.text() one by one to give the labels.
Here the code i use for creating dataset

```
jabar = [
['Depok',-6.385589,106.830711,'sedang',600],
['Tasikmalaya',-7.319563,108.202972,'sedang',600],
['Ciamis',-7.3299,108.3323,'sedang',600],
['Kuningan',-7.0138,108.5701,'sedang',600],
['Bogor',-6.497641,106.828224,'sedang',600],
['Bogor',-6.595038,106.816635,'sedang',600],
['Cirebon',-6.737246,108.550659,'sedang',600],
['Majalengka',-6.8364,108.2274,'sedang',600],
['Sumedang',-6.8381,107.9275,'sedang',600],
['Indramayu',-6.327583,108.324936,'sedang',600],
['Subang',-6.571589,107.758736,'sedang',600],
['Purwakarta',-6.538681,107.449944,'sedang',600],
['Karawang',-6.3227,107.3376,'sedang',600],
['Bekasi',-6.241586,106.992416,'sedang',600],
['Pangandaran',-7.6833,108.6500,'sedang',600],
['Sukabumi',-6.923700,106.928726,'sedang',600],
['Cimahi',-6.8841,107.5413,'sedang',600],
['Banjar',-7.374585,108.558189,'sedang',600],
['Cianjur',-6.734679,107.041252,'sedang',600],
['Bandung',-6.914864,107.608238,'tinggi',1000],
['Bandung',-6.905977,107.613144,'tinggi',1000],
['Bandung',-6.914744,107.609810,'tinggi',1000],
['Garut',-7.227906,107.908699,'sedang',600],
['Bandung Barat',-7.025253,107.519760,'sedang',600]]
features=['City','longitude','latitude','status','status_size']
risk_map = pd.DataFrame(jabar, columns=features)
```

and here it is the code i create for visualize to give the label each points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
plt.scatter(risk_map['latitude'],risk_map['longitude'], c='orange',
s=risk_map['status_size'], label='Risk region')
plt.title('Peta Sebaran Covid-19', fontsize=20)
plt.text(-7.227906,107.908699,'Garut')
plt.show()
```

actually i have two datasets exclude the code i write above, the another is about confirmed-positive-cases-covid-region which is the point about more than 500.000 points.
I merge this two dataset to get the risk-region. But i get trouble when i want to giva a labels on each point.
the plt.text() i write above is example to give a label on a point. it is impossible if i write one by one as same as the text code because my computer got cracked and blank after i executed that code.

Anyone have any idea to give a label on each points that i write the code above?
thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [plotly mapbox](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/) provides very simple to use capabilities for what you want
- your **longitude**,  **latitude** values are reversed.  See in code sample below I've reversed them

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


jabar = [
['Depok',-6.385589,106.830711,'sedang',600],
['Tasikmalaya',-7.319563,108.202972,'sedang',600],
['Ciamis',-7.3299,108.3323,'sedang',600],
['Kuningan',-7.0138,108.5701,'sedang',600],
['Bogor',-6.497641,106.828224,'sedang',600],
['Bogor',-6.595038,106.816635,'sedang',600],
['Cirebon',-6.737246,108.550659,'sedang',600],
['Majalengka',-6.8364,108.2274,'sedang',600],
['Sumedang',-6.8381,107.9275,'sedang',600],
['Indramayu',-6.327583,108.324936,'sedang',600],
['Subang',-6.571589,107.758736,'sedang',600],
['Purwakarta',-6.538681,107.449944,'sedang',600],
['Karawang',-6.3227,107.3376,'sedang',600],
['Bekasi',-6.241586,106.992416,'sedang',600],
['Pangandaran',-7.6833,108.6500,'sedang',600],
['Sukabumi',-6.923700,106.928726,'sedang',600],
['Cimahi',-6.8841,107.5413,'sedang',600],
['Banjar',-7.374585,108.558189,'sedang',600],
['Cianjur',-6.734679,107.041252,'sedang',600],
['Bandung',-6.914864,107.608238,'tinggi',1000],
['Bandung',-6.905977,107.613144,'tinggi',1000],
['Bandung',-6.914744,107.609810,'tinggi',1000],
['Garut',-7.227906,107.908699,'sedang',600],
['Bandung Barat',-7.025253,107.519760,'sedang',600]]
features=['City','longitude','latitude','status','status_size']
risk_map = pd.DataFrame(jabar, columns=features)

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(risk_map, lon="latitude", lat="longitude", 
                        color="status", hover_name="City",size="status_size"
                       )
fig.update_layout(mapbox={"style":"carto-positron"})

fig
```

[image]